# Copying a section of a string from one column and putting it into a new pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, split

I'm cleaning a dataset and need to take the part of the string between the underscores (_). Column A is what I am starting with.

```
A   
foo_bar_foo
bar_foo_bar
bar
foo_bar_foo
```

I need to copy over the characters in between the underscores and copy them into a new column. Column B is the anticipated results.

```
A               B
foo_bar_foo     bar
bar_foo_bar     foo
bar             null
foo_bar_foo     bar
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `bar_foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.split` and `.str[index]`

```
df['B']=df.A.str.split('_').str[1]



      A        B
0  foo_bar_foo  bar
1  bar_foo_bar  foo
2          bar  NaN
3  foo_bar_foo  bar
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.extract('_(\w+)_')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
             A    B
0  foo_bar_foo  bar
1  bar_foo_bar  foo
2          bar  NaN
3  foo_bar_foo  bar
```